# Clear button for multiple TextInput in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to put more than one `TextInput` here(1st-contact, 2nd-address) in single page and put a clear button at the end of the `TextInput`s which clears `TextInput`'s value. But I'm stuck how to make clear button visible when user clicks on individual `TextInput`. I tried `clearButtonMode="while-editing"` which doesn't allow me to give custom style. I also tried for single `TextInput` but I want for multiple `TextInput`. this one also [Is there a Cross platform clearButtonMode for Android with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793030/is-there-a-cross-platform-clearbuttonmode-for-android-with-react-native) & original doc suggests me to `setState` individually which increment my code size. My code is here:

```
    _handleCrossIcon() {
      //Here code logic which display clear button 
    }
    _handleCloseCrossIcon(index) {
      //Here code logic hide clear button
    }


    render(){
         return(
         <View>
           <View>
             <TextInput style={styles.edit_device_contact_txt}
                        editable = {true}
                        keyboardType = "number-pad"
                        onChangeText={(edit_u_contact) => {this.setState({u_contact: edit_u_contact})}}
                        value={ this.state.u_contact}
                        onFocus={this._handleCrossIcon}
                        onBlur={this._handleCloseCrossIcon}
             />
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._changeUserName('address_cross')} >
                <Icon style={s.edit_icon} name="ios-close" size={50} color="#00796b"/>
             </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View>
             <TextInput style={s.detail_txtinput}
                        editable = {true}
                        multiline = {true}
                        numberOfLines = {4}
                        onChangeText={(edit_address) => {this.setState({u_address: edit_address})}}
                        value={this.state.u_address}
                        onFocus={this._handleCrossIcon}
                        onBlur={this._handleCloseCrossIcon}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._changeUserName('address_cross')} >
                 <Icon style={s.edit_icon} name="ios-close" size={50} color="#00796b"/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
</View>
);
}
```

any help is appreciated. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common component named `InputWithClearButton`

https://github.com/zulip/zulip-mobile/blob/10.1.70/src/common/InputWithClearButton.js

and use this newly created component whenever you want a input with clear button. like this

https://github.com/zulip/zulip-mobile/blob/10.1.70/src/common/SearchInput.js#L32

This will definitely reduce your code size and will be easy to maintain.

Comment: this is good but in this example i've to put lots of files like types.js, Input.js, Touchable.js, nullObjects.js and also install `react-intl`. Do you have any short cut ?

Comment: Don't just copy mentioned file in my answer. Create your own `InputWithClearButton` taking reference from the mentioned file. I have added links just to give a basic idea. Idea is to create a component, which have clear button & input, and handle text clearing of input present in this component. And then use this newly created component everywhere in the app instead of `TextInput` from react-native whenever you want clear button for it.