# React-Native clear text button from TextInput

Tags: react-native, textinput

is there a way to clear all the text from a TextInput React component ?. I want an (X) to clear the text.

Also, I tried `clearButtonMode='always'` but this only works for IOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Cross platform clearButtonMode for Android with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793030/is-there-a-cross-platform-clearbuttonmode-for-android-with-react-native)